# Log the dropped packets by IPTables only if its DROPPED by a specific rule

Tags: logs, iptables

I have IPTables rules set on a Linux device. I have a particular rule to drop the packets, and  I wish to log the packets only if they're dropped by that specific rule, and not by the other rules.

Hence not written out to the syslog.

Answer (score 6):

You could use `rsyslog` and set a custom `--log-prefix` on this specific rule when you're setting it up. This would allow you to setup a `rsyslog` rule to route any messages with this custom prefix to a individual log file.

This tutorial titled: [Change the IPTables log file](http://www.networkinghowtos.com/howto/change-the-iptables-log-file/), shows the exact methodology. In general you'll setup your iptables rule like so:

```
$ sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 22 --syn -j LOG --log-prefix "iptables: "
```

And then create a corresponding `rsyslog` rule to log messages with this prefix:

```
# /etc/rsyslog.d/10-iptables.conf
:msg, contains, "iptables: " -/var/log/iptables.log
& ~
```